Using URL Parameters in ArcGIS Online
I have a dashboard that is typically opened from a primary dashboard. The workflow is that a user filters for a single item on the primary dashboard, which provides them with a link to the sub-dashboard. I want to use URL parameters such that when, for example, the user selects itemID = 123, and is provided a link to the sub-dashboard, when they open the link, this second dashboard automatically filters for itemID=123, changing the map extent and only including that item in the list widget.
I've tried doing so according to what I've read at this link by adding filters to both the primary and sub dashboards. However, I can't figure out how to actually add the parameters to the end of the URL as outlined on this page. Is this possible in ArcGIS Online?

In order to configure the parameter like you are talking about, you are close but you have the URL Parameter Configuration Wrong in the dashboard settings -
You would need to set the parameter to be a Feature parameter, and set the unique field id to be the field that has the relevant data. See https://developers.arcgis.com/documentation/app-builders/no-code/tutorials/tools/customize-dashboard-url-parameter/#configure-url-parameter
After this, you would just need to set your URL to be "https://.com/apps/dashboards/#param="
